# mysql procedure, loop tables, set default value

Tags: mysql

I have created a small stored procedure to set some defaults before inserting data (I use PhpMyAdmin) in some tables

```
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE capacitors MODIFY COLUMN `Part Type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Ceramic Multilayer MLCC';
ALTER TABLE capacitors MODIFY COLUMN `Package` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0603';
END
```

How can I create a procedure to make defaults in many tables for 'Distributor' and 'Distributor Currency' fields?

Pseudo:

FOR EACH table in database

```
IF field 'Distributor' exists -> set default to 'Mouser'
IF filed 'Distributor Currency' exists -> set default to 'USD'
```

Comment: Why would you do something like that? Thats not what defaults are for.

Comment: Because I eneter manually several components with the same fields. Why write every time the same values?

Comment: Well thats not why you use defaults, you don't keep altering the table like that.  Create a function, add the defaults in there and pass them into the record.

Comment: On top, i don't know your datamodel, but inserting 'Mouser' doesn't look like a normalised database (look for database normalisation according to Codd).

Comment: I think, because of that in MySQL you can't have a `CURSOR` you can't have a SP like that you want, But I suggest you to use triggers ;).